# Results of applying logarithm to numerator and denominator of limit

Tags: limits

I want to calculate the following limit:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{log_2(n!)}{nlog_2(n)}$

I know that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}=0$, and I think that, since the logarithm is a monotonically increasing function with no upper bounds, the limit I want to calculate will be equal to 0. But I cannot prove it.

I would also like to know if what I assumed before is correct for any functions, and if so if there is a proof for it. That is:

If for 2 functions it is true that:
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$

is it also true that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{h(f(x))}{h(g(x))}=0$

where h is a monotonically increasing function with no upper bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that you can split the numerator into 
$$\log{n}+\log{(n-1)}+...+\log{2}$$
So when dividing by $n\log{n}$, we can split the fraction into
$$\frac{\log{n}}{n\log{n}}+\frac{\log{(n-1)}}{n\log{n}}+\frac{\log{2}}{n\log{n}}$$
Viewed this way, we can see the limit is indeed $0$.

For your second question, observe that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$
means that for any (small) $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $x_{0}$ such that whenever $x>x_{0}$ we have 
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<\epsilon$$
We can rephrase this as "eventually $f(x)<\epsilon g(x)$". Now, if $h$ is strictly increasing, this implies that 
$$h(f(x)) < h(\epsilon g(x))$$
However, what we want to say is that
$$h(f(x))<\epsilon h(g(x))$$
An general proof is escaping me (and perhaps it's not true in general), but I'll point out that if $h$ is assumed to be convex (or any function satisfying $h(ax)<ah(x))$, then this follows immediately.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any proof/disproof about the hypothesis in the second part of my question?

Comment: @michailvazaios It's not clear what you're asking for the second part, perhaps you left something out

Comment: Yes you are right. I forgot the =0 in the last two limits. I just editted it

Comment: @michailvazaios I've updated my answer

Comment: I think I have a counter example. Suppose $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=x$. The limit as x approaches infinity of $f(x)/g(x)$ is 0. Let $h(x)=ln x$. Then lim x-> inf of $h(f(x))/h(g(x))=-inf$